SVG Clip Mask Over Video Not Displaying in Safari
I successfully created an SVG clip mask using a company logo that is supposed to be used as a mask over a video montage. However, it works in every browser except for Safari. I have scoured this site and others and tried many solutions to get this video mask to work in Safari to no avail. I'm very much hoping that someone here can help. Please see my code below. Thanks!
Logo Mask Video HTML


.parent_videologo_container {
    width: 100%;
}

.videologo {
    clip-path: url(#videologomask);
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#videologomask);
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.videologo_container {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; 
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.3;
}


.parent_videologo_container img {
    position:absolute;
    top: 8.5%;
    bottom:0;
    left: 4.5%;
    right:0;
    width: 55%;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px #000000);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px #000000);
    z-index: 100;
}
<div class="parent_videologo_container">
    <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/61ae7bac2fe6511670e0d1d8/t/65f1cf711fea292ed70a3160/1710346097599/Method%2BLogo%2BPrimary_NoTagline.png" />
    <div class="videologo_container">
        <video class="videologo" autoplay playsinline muted loop width="100%" height="100%" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/61ae7bac2fe6511670e0d1d8/t/6602cf3d75fd305fdcbdcaca/1711460158389/BGVideoV2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidyMin meet">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="videologomask" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <path d="M.048645,0c-.026733,0-.048645.021912-.048645.048645v.189758c0,.026733.021912.048645.048645.048645h.189758c.026733,0,.048645-.021912.048645-.048645V.048645c0-.026733-.021912-.048645-.048645-.048645H.048645ZM.405151,0c-.026794,0-.048645.021912-.048645.048645v.189758c0,.026733.021851.048645.048645.048645h.189697c.026794,0,.048645-.021912.048645-.048645V.048645c0-.026733-.021851-.048645-.048645-.048645h-.189697ZM.951355,0h-.189758c-.026733,0-.048645.021912-.048645.048645v.189758c0,.026733.021912.048645.048645.048645h.189758c.026733,0,.048645-.021912.048645-.048645V.048645c0-.026733-.021912-.048645-.048645-.048645ZM.048645.356506c-.026733,0-.048645.021851-.048645.048645v.189697c0,.026794.021912.048645.048645.048645h.189758c.026733,0,.048645-.021851.048645-.048645v-.189697c0-.026794-.021912-.048645-.048645-.048645H.048645ZM.405151.356506c-.026794,0-.048645.021851-.048645.048645v.189697c0,.026794.021851.048645.048645.048645h.189697c.026794,0,.048645-.021851.048645-.048645v-.189697c0-.026794-.021851-.048645-.048645-.048645h-.189697ZM.761597.356506c-.026733,0-.048645.021851-.048645.048645v.189697c0,.026794.021912.048645.048645.048645h.189758c.026733,0,.048645-.021851.048645-.048645v-.189697c0-.026794-.021912-.048645-.048645-.048645h-.189758ZM.048645.712952c-.026733,0-.048645.021912-.048645.048645v.189758c0,.026733.021912.048645.048645.048645h.189758c.026733,0,.048645-.021912.048645-.048645v-.189758c0-.026733-.021912-.048645-.048645-.048645,0,0-.189758,0-.189758,0ZM.405151.712952c-.026794,0-.048645.021912-.048645.048645v.189758c0,.026733.021851.048645.048645.048645h.189697c.026794,0,.048645-.021912.048645-.048645v-.189758c0-.026733-.021851-.048645-.048645-.048645,0,0-.189697,0-.189697,0ZM.761597.712952c-.026733,0-.048645.021912-.048645.048645v.189758c0,.026733.021912.048645.048645.048645h.189758c.026733,0,.048645-.021912.048645-.048645v-.189758c0-.026733-.021912-.048645-.048645-.048645,0,0-.189758,0-.189758,0Z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>




Does this issue apply to Safari for iOS, Safari for Mac, or both?

Hi @Brandon. Thanks for taking a look. It applies to both Safari for iOS and Mac. I saw some solutions that used iframes and others that said it had to do with the foreignObject tag that Safari uses but none of them worked. Do you have any ideas?

Hi @Brandon, any ideas on how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Clip the video container instead. Seems like safari has problems applying clip-paths directly to video elements.
